# A problem occurred configuring project ':@volst_react-native-tuya'

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, tuya, bluebase

I am working on an **Expo** Project. I have installed @volst/react-native-tuya by using

```
yarn add @volst/react-native-tuya
```

and I'm using their **0.3.14 Version**. I read all this documentation from [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@volst/react-native-tuya/v/0.3.14)
and follow all steps.

But after I install and try to run on android I'm Facing an issue which is:

> A problem occurred configuring project ':@volst_react-native-tuya'.
> Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':@volst_react-native-tuya:classpath'.
> > Using insecure protocols with repositories, without explicit opt-in, is unsupported. Switch Maven repository 'maven(http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/)' to redirect to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.

[image: That's the error]

I do all my efforts but can't resolve this.

**My Package.json File**

```
{
   "name": "@mevris/client-plugin-installation-components",
   "description": "The Add flow driver",
   "author": "BlueEast Team <code@blueeast.com>",
   "version": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
   "main": "dist/index.js",
   "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
   "module": "dist/index.js",
   "repository": {
     "type": "git",
     "url": "https://github.com/BlueEastCode/mevris-client-plugin-installation-components"
   },
   "remarkConfig": {
    "plugins": [
       "remark-preset-lint-recommended"
     ]
   },
   "config": {
     "react-native-storybook-loader": {
        "searchDir": [
         "src"
       ],
       "pattern": "**/*.stories.tsx",
       "outputFile": "./storybook/storyLoader.js"
     }
   },
   "scripts": {
     ...
   },
   "dependencies": {
     ...

     "@volst/react-native-tuya": "^0.3.0",
     "expo": "~45.0.0",
     "expo-barcode-scanner": "^11.4.0",
     "expo-location": "~14.2.2",
     "expo-splash-screen": "~0.15.1",
     "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
     "react": "17.0.2",
     "react-dom": "17.0.2",
     "react-native": "0.68.2",
     "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
     "react-native-wifi-reborn": "^4.7.0",
     "yup": "^0.32.11"
   },
   "resolutions": {
     "@types/react": "17.0.2",
     "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2",
     "graphql": "^16.5.0"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     ...
   },
   "prettier": {
     "singleQuote": true,
     "useTabs": true,
     "trailingComma": "es5"
   },
   "publishConfig": {
     "access": "public"
   },
   "peerDependencies": {
     "yup": "^0.32.11"
   }
 }
```

**My Settings.gradle File**
[image: My Settings.gradle File]
**My android/build.gradle**

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

 buildscript {
     ext {
         buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '31.0.0'
         minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '21')
         compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '31')
         targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '31')
         if (findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')) {
             kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion')
         }
         frescoVersion = findProperty('expo.frescoVersion') ?: '2.5.0'

         if (System.properties['os.arch'] == 'aarch64') {
             // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
             ndkVersion = '24.0.8215888'
         } else {
             // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
             ndkVersion = '21.4.7075529'
         }
     }
     repositories {
         google()
         mavenCentral()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4')
         classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
         classpath('de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2')
         // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
              // in the individual module build.gradle files
     }
 }

 allprojects {
     repositories {
         mavenLocal()
         maven {
             // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
             url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
         }
         maven {
             // Android JSC is installed from npm
             url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
         }

         google()
         maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
                 jcenter() {
                     allowInsecureProtocol = true
                 }
         mavenCentral {
             // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
             // older versions over there.
             content {
                 excludeGroup 'com.facebook.react'
             }
         }
         maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Yes! I'm using Groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the package itself, since it calls the url mentioned in the issue without setting allowInsecureProtocol to true, and of course https based url is not available. You can fix it this way, it is kinda hacky but as long as the dev doesn't push an update, none can do anything afaik.

1. Go the package folder `node_modules/@volst/react-native-tuya/android` and open `build.gradle` file.
2. Replace

   `maven{url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'}`

with this:

```
maven {
      url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/'
      allowInsecureProtocol = true
}
```

3. An extra but recommended step, use patch-package to create a temporary fix (https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package)

Comment: It didn't work. I applied these changes to my package but It could not fixed. The Error is still same.

Comment: Did you change the package itself? (Oh and don't forget, whenever you run npm install, your changes will be overwritten, that's why I said step 3 is recommended).

Comment: It would not effect my code.

Comment: No, it won't affect your code and unfortunately it can't be fixed without patch-package until the package author fixes it himself.

Answer (score 0):

It was the issue of the plugin. I clone this plugin and resolve this by updating some code base.

If you were also facing this issue you can resolve this by installing @artalat/react-native-tuya on your package.json.